# Filling areas under multiple adjacent curves

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fillbetween

I want to shade the area of overlap for adjacent normal curves, shown in the lower graph. I can get shading between the first two curves but not for subsequent curves. I need shading at overlapping areas indicated by the arrows. I applied the "logic" of the first fill for the subsequent curves but that does not work.

The arrows and letters in the example image are not part of the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%normal distribution where #1 = mean and #2 = sd}
    \pgfmathparse{exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}

\pgfplotsset{baseplot/.style={%
    no markers, 
    domain=1:4.5, 
    samples=100,
    smooth,
    axis lines*=left,
    height=5cm, width=12cm,
    enlargelimits=upper, clip=false, axis on top,
    xlabel = near ticks,
    xlabel={Resource}
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[baseplot]
  \addplot+[name path=A]{gauss(2.7,0.4)};
  \addplot+[name path=B]{gauss(3.2,0.4)};
  \fill[gray!20, intersection segments ={of= B and A}];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace*{3\baselineskip}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[baseplot]
  \addplot+[name path=A]{gauss(1.7,0.15)};
  \addplot+[name path=B]{gauss(2.2, 0.15)};
  \addplot+[name path=C]{gauss(2.7, 0.15)};
  \addplot+[name path=D]{gauss(3.2, 0.15)};
  \addplot+[name path=E]{gauss(3.7, 0.15)};
  \fill[gray!20, intersection segments ={of= B and A}];
  \fill[gray!20, intersection segments ={of= C and B}];
  \fill[gray!20, intersection segments ={of= D and C}];
  \fill[gray!20, intersection segments ={of= E and D}];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think your case doesn't work as expected, because you draw all Gaussian plots in the full `domain` (from 1 to 4.5) and so a lot of points are very near together (at y = 0) which I think makes it really hard for TikZ/PGFPlots to calculate the intersections.

When you provide a unique `domain` to each `\addplot` this has two advantages.

1. The lines near y = 0 don't "overlap" any more and thus the "real" intersection points can be found much easier, and
2. by providing a unique `domain` to each `\addplot` you will either get a much more smooth plot with the given `samples` or you can decrease the `samples`.

For more details have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.3,
        baseplot/.style={
            width=12cm,
            height=5cm,
            axis lines*=left,
            axis on top,
            enlargelimits=upper,
            xlabel={Resource},
            ticks=none,
            no markers,
            samples=100,
            smooth,
        },
        /pgf/declare function={
            % normal distribution where \mean = mean and \stddev = sd}
            gauss(\mean,\stddev)=exp(-((x-\mean)^2)/(2*\stddev^2));
        },
    }
    % to simplify the input, which repeats all the time, create a command
    % here #1 = `name path', #2 = `\mean', #3 = `\stddev'
    % the idea is that the gauss values are almost zero after 4 standard
    % deviations and so the `samples' can be better used in that ±4 standard
    % deviation range around the mean value
    % (this has the positive side effect that the lines of two neighboring
    %  gauss plots don't overlap in the "zero" range and thus makes it
    %  much easier for TikZ/PGFPlots to identify the "real" intersections.)
    \newcommand*\myaddplot[3]{
        \addplot+ [name path=#1,domain=#2-4*#3:#2+4*#3] {gauss(#2,#3)};
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            baseplot,
            % activate layers
            set layers,
        ]
            \myaddplot{A}{1.7}{0.15}
            \myaddplot{B}{2.2}{0.15}
            \myaddplot{C}{2.7}{0.15}
            \myaddplot{D}{3.2}{0.15}
            \myaddplot{E}{3.7}{0.15}

            % draw the "fill between" stuff on a lower layer
            % (otherwise half of the `\addplot' lines with be overdrawn
            %  by the fills)
            \pgfonlayer{pre main}
                \fill[gray!20, intersection segments={of=B and A}];
                \fill[gray!20, intersection segments={of=C and B}];
                \fill[gray!20, intersection segments={of=D and C}];
                \fill[gray!20, intersection segments={of=E and D}];
            \endpgfonlayer
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Your answer was enlightening and also greatly sped up the compilation time by reducing the calculation time. Thank you.

Comment: Your answer inspired me to ask one question; is it possible to easily replace my hobby curve [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/438340/2288) with Gaussian one, or will it take some effort to do so?

Comment: @Diaa, I don't think that I get your question right. But in general you can replace a path by a function, of course. But after having a short look at your question I don't know what exactly the gaussian curve/function would be good for.