# Drawing 2D ellipses on the xy plane of 3D pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

I have taken information I learned from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338876/filling-areas-under-multiple-adjacent-curves) to make a 3D plot using `pgfplots`. I can plot the normal distribution on the x- and y-axes but I cannot figure out how to plot the corresponding ellipses on the xy plane, as shown here. (Overall, the z dimension is not necessary for my purpose.) The ellipses do not need to spread the full length of the tails from the normal distributions. Probably 2-3 standard deviation units is fine (assuming that can be done). My purpose for the figure is to illustrate a concept so it does not have to be super precise.

[image]

I tried using `contour gnuplot` but I do not need contour lines. I just need a smooth ellipse for each pair of normal distributions (blue and red pairs). In addition, the contours here are boxy. The code I tried is commented in the MWE below.

[image]

I tried using the `scope` environment from the `tikz` 3d library but I could not get the circle to move from the lower left corner of the plot. The code I tried is commented in the MWE.

[image]

Although I said the third dimension is unnecessary, I would also not mind seeing the result as a surface plot instead of ellipses to see if it might better suit my purpose. I have no idea where to begin. It would need to be colored to show the overlapping region, although a blend of the curve colors could be used instead of gray, perhaps.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.3,
        3dbaseplot/.style={
            width=12cm,
            height=7cm,
            axis lines*=left,
            axis on top,
            enlargelimits=upper,
            xlabel={Temperature},
            ylabel={Soil pH},
            ticks=none,
            no markers,
            samples=30,
            samples y=0,
            smooth,
        },
        /pgf/declare function={
            % normal distribution where \mean = mean and \stddev = sd}
      normal(\mean,\stddev)=1/(2*\stddev*sqrt(pi))*exp(-(x-\mean)^2/(2*\stddev^2));
        },
        /pgf/declare function={%
            bivar(\meanA,\stddevA,\meanB,\stddevB)=1/(2*pi*\stddevA*\stddevB) * exp(-((x-\meanA)^2/\stddevA^2 + (y-\meanB)^2/\stddevB^2))/2;
        },
    }
    \newcommand*\myaddplotX[4]{
        \addplot3+ [name path=#1,domain=#2-4*#3:#2+4*#3, color=#4] (x,4,{normal(#2,#3)});
    }
    \newcommand*\myaddplotY[4]{
        \addplot3+ [name path=#1,domain=#2-4*#3:#2+4*#3, color=#4] (1,x,{normal(#2,#3)});
    }

% Added to try the scope environment
\usetikzlibrary{3d}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            3dbaseplot,
            set layers,
        ]
          \myaddplotX{A}{2}{0.25}{blue}
          \myaddplotX{B}{2.2}{0.25}{red}
          \myaddplotY{C}{2.7}{0.15}{red}
          \myaddplotY{D}{3.2}{0.15}{blue}

%% I don't think contour is really what I want.
%     \addplot3+[contour gnuplot={,labels=false}, samples y=41,domain y=1:3, z filter/.code=\def\pgfmathresult{0}] {bivar(2,0.25,3.2,0.15)};

% This may be the path to nirvana but I can't figure out how to apply it properly.            
%         \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
%            \draw (2,3.2) circle (0.5cm);
%         \end{scope}
            \pgfonlayer{pre main}
               \fill[gray!20, intersection segments={of=B and A}];
               \fill[gray!20, intersection segments={of=D and C}];
            \endpgfonlayer
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were thinking quite too complicated. Just draw the ellipses with the `ellipse` or `circle` (they are equivalent) command from TikZ. The rest should then be straight forward (hopefully) ...

Again: For more details have a look at the comments in the code.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
    \pgfplotsset{
        % change `compat level to 1.11 or higher so you don't need to
        % prefix every tikz coordinate with `axis cs:'
        compat=1.11,
        3dbaseplot/.style={
            width=12cm,
            height=7cm,
            axis lines*=left,
            axis on top,
            enlargelimits=upper,
            xlabel={Temperature},
            ylabel={Soil pH},
            ticks=none,
            no markers,
            samples=30,
            samples y=0,
            smooth,
        },
        /pgf/declare function={
            % normal distribution where \mean = mean and \stddev = sd
            normal(\mean,\stddev)=1/(2*\stddev*sqrt(pi))*exp(-(x-\mean)^2/(2*\stddev^2));
        },
    }
    \newcommand*\myaddplotX[4]{
        \addplot3+ [name path=#1,domain=#2-4*#3:#2+4*#3,color=#4]
            (x,4,{normal(#2,#3)});
    }
    \newcommand*\myaddplotY[4]{
        \addplot3+ [name path=#1,domain=#2-4*#3:#2+4*#3, color=#4]
            (1,x,{normal(#2,#3)});
    }
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            3dbaseplot,
            set layers,
        ]
            \myaddplotX{A}{2.0}{0.25}{blue}
            \myaddplotX{B}{2.2}{0.25}{red}
            \myaddplotY{C}{2.7}{0.15}{red}
            \myaddplotY{D}{3.2}{0.15}{blue}

            \pgfonlayer{pre main}
               \fill[gray!20, intersection segments={of=B and A}];
               \fill[gray!20, intersection segments={of=D and C}];
            \endpgfonlayer

            % -----------------------------------------------------------------
                % create a variable that stores the factor of the standard
                % deviations for that the ellipses should be drawn
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\factor}{2.5}
            % draw the ellipses
            \draw [blue,x radius=\factor*0.25,y radius=\factor*0.15]
                (2.0,3.2,0) ellipse;
            \draw [red,x radius=\factor*0.25,y radius=\factor*0.15]
                (2.2,2.7,0) ellipse;

            % again, to draw the fill we use the other layer
            \pgfonlayer{pre main}
                % repeat the drawing of the ellipses, but this time as clip pathes
                \clip [x radius=\factor*0.25,y radius=\factor*0.15]
                    (2.0,3.2,0) ellipse;
                \clip [x radius=\factor*0.25,y radius=\factor*0.15]
                    (2.2,2.7,0) ellipse;
                % then you can just fill the full xy plane and it does not need
                % to be adjusted any more
                \fill [gray!20]
                    (rel axis cs:0,0,0) -- (rel axis cs:1,0,0)
                        -- (rel axis cs:1,1,0) -- (rel axis cs:0,1,0) -- cycle;
            \endpgfonlayer
            % -----------------------------------------------------------------
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Is there a way to rotate the clipped gray area? I tried changing the angle of the plot with `view/h=50` in the 3dbaseplot style. Everything rotated just fine except for the gray of the overlapping ellipses.

Comment: Both overthinking and underthinking are the hallmarks (and bane) of my life. Thank you once again.

Comment: Ok, I don't know what you wanted to say with your last comment, but I think you found the solution to the comment question yourself, right?

Comment: No, I did not find a solution to my comment question. My statement comment was in reference to a statement a the start of your answer and an expression of appreciation.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with "rotate the clipped gray area". Would you mind asking a new question and again sketch what you want to achieve and add the stuff to the code that you have already tried (commented is also fine) -- as you did exemplary  in this question?

Comment: I think I figured out the problem. If I use view/h=X where X is a number between 30 and 60, the amount of overlapping space filled in for the ellipses varies. For example, view/h=50 rotates the entire plot but the overlap shows a narrow band of gray that extends (relatively) from 0,0 to 1,1 but most of the space is white. `rel axis` should fill the entire plane but apparently does not. The pgfplots manual indicates that \clip is experimental so I suspect this is a bug. I will post an example in a day or so when I have more time. For now, your answer suits my needs. As always, thank you.

Comment: No, it is not a bug; it was a fault of me. The `rectangle` was the problem. It is a "2D" command and than of course TikZ cannot "know" in plane the rectangle should be drawn (I think). I have edited my answer, where now the xy plane really is totally filled. Hopefully now you can make the modifications without any more problems.